# Error creating Matrix in EMGU CV

Tags: vb.net, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

The error happens in this line:

```
Dim imageMatrix = New Emgu.CV.Matrix(Of Double)(100, 120)
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.World.dll

```
CvInvoke.cvInitMatHeader(_ptr, _array.GetLength(0), _array.GetLength(1), CvInvoke.MakeType( CvInvoke.GetDepthType(typeof(TDepth)), 1), _dataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 0x7fffffff);
```

Is this a declaration or library error?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Isn't there any error message? Have you checked the InnerException?

Comment: Emgu.CV.CvInvoke made an exception, I added the line of error

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for this 'System.TypeInitializationException' is that your project is not able to find all dlls from EMGU.Place all dlls(including opencv) from Emgu/bin/x64 or x86 into your project release/dubug folder . That will solve the problem.Setting environmental  path variable for EMGU could also helps.